# boost thread: object modified after being freed

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm trying to create a simple multi-threaded application with boost thread. Basically I have to compute about 100 things and would like to split it into 8 threads at a time. The only tricky aspects are that I need to pass a pointer to the workers, and then get some return values. In the example below the pointer is just to a float but in my real application it's a bigger class. This segfaults. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Wrote as a standalone file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Worker {
public:
  Worker(boost::atomic<int> & threads,
         boost::mutex & mutex,
         boost::condition_variable & condition):
    threads_(threads), mutex_(mutex), condition_(condition){}
  void do_stuff(int num, float * num2){
    results_.reserve(num);
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
      results_.push_back(*num2);
    }
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
    threads_--;
    condition_.notify_one();
  }
  std::vector<float> results_;
private:
  boost::atomic<int> & threads_;
  boost::mutex & mutex_;
  boost::condition_variable & condition_;
};

int main(){
  int ntasks = 25;
  std::vector<Worker> workers;
  workers.reserve(ntasks);
  boost::thread_group thread_group;
  boost::mutex mutex;
  boost::condition_variable condition;
  boost::atomic<int> threads(0);
  float * bean;
  *bean = 3.14159;
  for(int iz=0;iz<ntasks;iz++){
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
    while (threads >= 8) condition.wait(lock);
    Worker w = Worker(threads, mutex, condition);
    workers.push_back(w);
    boost::function<void()> th_func = boost::bind(&Worker::do_stuff,
                                                  &workers.back(),5,bean);
    boost::thread * thread = new boost::thread(th_func);
    thread_group.add_thread(thread);
    threads++;
  }
  thread_group.join_all();

  //inspect the results
  for (int iw=0;iw<workers.size();iw++){
    for (int it=0;it<5;it++){
      cout<<workers[iw].results_[it]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

On my mac compiled with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o thread -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt
```

Comment: For questions  like this, please always post a [MCVE]

Comment: when you pass `&w` to the new thread, it goes out of scope at the end of the current for iteration. you should pass either a copy of the object or the address of a variable that won't go out of scope while the new thread is running, like passing &workers.back() after reserving enough space so later push_back calls don't reallocate the array inside workers. Also, you need to wait for the threads to finish writing the results by destroying the thread_group or something before you read them.

Comment: If you are on linux, I'd suggest using valgrind with the helgrind tool, it finds thread synchronization problems.

Comment: @m.s. I've written it as a complete example (that compiles for me but segfaults!

Comment: @programmerjake I incorporated your suggestion but still no dice.

Comment: where you have *bean= 3...; bean doesn't point to anything, you need to assign bean (not *bean) a value first. try something like `float beanValue; float *bean = &beanValue;`

Comment: @programmerjake Thanks! Looks like I had a bug somewhere else. But writing the standalone script helped prove it was right! I'll leave it up in case anyone needs a thread starter...

Answer (score 0):

where you have `*bean = 3.14159;` `bean` doesn't point to anything, you need to assign `bean` (not `*bean`) a value first. try something like

```
float beanValue;
float *bean = &beanValue;
*bean = 3.14159;
```